# Angular check conditonal AFTER getting values from subscribe in observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

**Goal:** Check IF conditional after getting data from array

**What I've tried:**
I tried looking at a number of other articles on SO that asked about a similar question, but they seemed to be a little different. I need to wait until the entire Array is filled before going to the IF condition

I tried moving the IF condition inside the subscription but it gets called multiple times.

**Debugger**: Its going from the call to getV() to the method, but when it gets to the first subscribe it goes back to the IF statement.

**Typescript**:

```
    ngOnInit {
     this.getV(vId);
     if (this.internalNotes.length > 0) {
              this.dialog.open(DialogInternalNotesThreeComponent, {
                  data: {
                      data: this.internalNotes
                  }
              });
          }
      
    }

    public getV(vId: number) {
        this.vs.V(vId)
            .subscribe(resp => {
                this.ps.GetPInternalNotes(resp.PID.toString()).subscribe(respPIN => {
                    for (let index = 0; index < respPIN.length; index++) {
                        this.internalNotes.push(respPIN[index]);
                        
                    }
                });
            });         
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Putting it immediately after the FOR statement in the subscribe seems to resolve the multiple dialogs. Does this look correct?

```
public getV(vId: number) {
        this.vs.V(vId)
            .subscribe(resp => {
                this.ps.GetPInternalNotes(resp.PID.toString()).subscribe(respPIN => {
                    for (let index = 0; index < respPIN.length; index++) {
                        this.internalNotes.push(respPIN[index]);
                    }
                    if (this.internalNotes.length > 0) {
                        this.dialog.open(DialogInternalNotesThreeComponent, {
                            data: {
                                data: this.internalNotes
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });         
    }
```

Comment: Your edit is correct. In order to check the length of the array, your conditional statement needs to be a part of the subscription block where you have immediate access to the value being subscribed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand observables, you expect this code to run sync (aka line by line) but this is not the essence of reactive programming.

```
this.getV(vId);
if (this.internalNotes.length > 0)
```

by reaching the `if` the array is not necessarily initialized since we might reach this line while the observable did not push
`respPIN[index]` to the array yet.

that's why `Putting it immediately after the FOR statement in the subscribe seems to resolve the multiple dialogs` works.

if you want to keep your behaviour you want to return an observable of that array inside your `getV()`

```
ngOnInit {
  // subscribe to the returned array
  this.getV(vId).subscribe(
       (internalNotes) => {
            if (internalNotes.length > 0) {
                this.dialog.open(DialogInternalNotesThreeComponent, {
                    data: {
                        data: internalNotes
                    }
                });
              }
        });
 }

 // method returns an observable with your array
 public getV(vId: number): Observable<Array<any>> {
     this.vs.V(vId)
         .subscribe(resp => {
             this.ps.GetPInternalNotes(resp.PID.toString()).subscribe(respPIN => {
                 for (let index = 0; index < respPIN.length; index++) {
                     this.internalNotes.push(respPIN[index]); 
                 }
                 // return an observable with your current array
                 return of(this.internalNotes);
             });
         });

    // base case return an empty observable  
    return EMPTY;       
 }
```